# How to genereate type definitions with bun build bundle?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, type-definition, bun

To create a bundle I run this command in CLI:

```bash
bun build ./index.ts --outdir ./build
```

The `tsconfig.json` contains this configuration:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
  },
}
```

A single bundled file `.build/index.js` will be created.
Which is good.

In addition I would like to have all type definitions that are used bundled in a single .d.ts file.

How do I get this file?

Answer (score 0):

Bun [can't build](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/5141) type definitions.

So, the only alternative is to run `tsc --emitDeclarationOnly` for generating type definitions.